# Why am I unable to generate a Firebase app check token on an iOS simulator in an Expo project?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, firebase-app-check

I am trying to generate a Firebase app check token on an iOS simulator in an Expo project and am encountering the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "App attestation failed.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I have taken the following steps:

Went into Firebase -> Settings -> App Check and created a debug token in Manage debug tokens.
Added the debug token to my eas.json file like this:

```
"env": {
        "FIREBASE_APP_CHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN": "***********",
        "FIRAAppCheckDebugToken": "********",
        "FIREBASE_APP_CHECK_DEBUG": "true"
      }
```

Installed and imported the @react-native-firebase/app-check package in my project.
Called the "activate" like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  appCheck().activate("ignored", true);
}, []);
```

When i try a fetch request to my local firebase backend using appCheckTokenResponse = await appCheck().getToken(); and adding to headers "X-Firebase-AppCheck": appCheckTokenResponse.token i receive "PERMISSION_DENIED" because no token is generated.

Any help?